# Tag "function" e "função"

Tags: debate, tags

Hoje apareceu na lista de revisão de entradas wiki das tags [function](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function) e [função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o). Eu rejeitei o edit para [function](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function) pois só tinha uma pergunta com a tag (que "[des-taguei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/27401/revisions)").

Eu pessoalmente acho ambas pouco uteis pois isso é o mesmo que ter uma tag [variable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable) que não faz muito sentido. O que acham vocês?

Se acharem que eu estou errado elas devem pelo menos ser sinónimos.

Comment: A menos que se trate de uma pergunta conceitual sobre funções (o que não é um caso em nenhuma das presentes), de fato essas tags não fazem muito sentido. Sugiro removê-las por ora, e se no futuro alguém criar uma pergunta *pertinente* que use a tag "função" (recriando-a), aí mantemos.

Comment: Parece haver bastante apoio pela remoção. Alguém se habilita?

Comment: @bigown, feito. Agora é só esperar até o sistema fazer desaparacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o [@mgibsonbr sugeriu](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1786/tag-function-e-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o#comment5170_1786) e muitos concordaram ainda não apareceu uma pergunta que precise de uma tag function ou função.

Assim, removí as tags e se no futuro forem necessárias re-criamos.

Comment: **[Algo me diz](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/30236/revisions)** que essas tags vão querer voltar com frequência.